# Merge sql into a stored procedure for better performace

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am still having real performance issue in a list there our 38 thousand entrys and I need to map them to another table for export I am thinking of moving it to stored proc but still worried what performance would be like there. The code works but takes a very long time to execute and wish to turn it into a stored proc.

```
private List<TradeItemsExport> MapTradeItems(List<TradeItems> tradeItem)
{
    List<TradeItemsExport> retList = new List<TradeItemsExport>();

    try
    {
        var StockImport = new StockItemExported();

        List<StandardLookUpList> _AnalsisCodes = GetAnayalsisCodesForExportCode();

        StandardLookUpList sport = new StandardLookUpList();
        StandardLookUpList gender = new StandardLookUpList();
        StandardLookUpList colour = new StandardLookUpList();
        StandardLookUpList Size = new StandardLookUpList();
        StandardLookUpList categorycode = new StandardLookUpList();
        StandardLookUpList categorydesc = new StandardLookUpList();
        StandardLookUpList subcategorycode = new StandardLookUpList();
        StandardLookUpList subcategorydesc = new StandardLookUpList();

        StandardLookUpList brandcode = new StandardLookUpList();
        StandardLookUpList branddesc = new StandardLookUpList();

        using (var db = new liveEntities1())
        {
            int count = 0;

            foreach (var item in tradeItem)
            {
                count++;
                bool hasprocessed = HasTransactionBeenProcessed(item.ItemCode);

                if (hasprocessed == false)
                {
                    var codesForThisItem = _AnalsisCodes.Where(w => w.ItemCode == item.ItemCode);

                    if (codesForThisItem.Any())
                    {
                        sport = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Sport);

                        gender = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Gender);
                        colour = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Colour);
                        Size = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Size);
                        categorycode = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Category);
                        categorydesc = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Category);

                        subcategorycode = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.SubCategory);
                        subcategorydesc = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.SubCategory);
                        brandcode = codesForThisItem.FirstOrDefault(x => x.code == Constants.Brand);

                        string SportCodeValue, SportDescValue;

                        if (sport == null)
                        {
                            SportCodeValue = "";
                            SportDescValue = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SportCodeValue = sport.LookupValue.ToString();
                            SportDescValue = sport.description;
                        }

                        string GenderCodeValue, GenderCodeDesc;

                        if (gender == null)
                        {
                            GenderCodeValue = "";
                            GenderCodeDesc = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            GenderCodeValue = gender.LookupValue.ToString();
                            GenderCodeDesc = gender.description;
                        }

                        string ColourCodeValue, ColourCodeDesc;

                        if (colour == null)
                        {
                            ColourCodeValue = "";
                            ColourCodeDesc = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ColourCodeValue = colour.LookupValue.ToString();
                            ColourCodeDesc = colour.description;
                        }

                        string SizeCodeValue, SizeCodeDesc;

                        if (Size == null)
                        {
                            SizeCodeValue = "";
                            SizeCodeDesc = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SizeCodeValue = Size.LookupValue.ToString();
                            SizeCodeDesc = Size.description;
                        }

                        string CategoryCodeValue, CategoryCodeDesc;

                        if (categorycode == null)
                        {
                            CategoryCodeValue = "";
                            CategoryCodeDesc = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CategoryCodeValue = categorycode.LookupValue.ToString();
                            CategoryCodeDesc = categorydesc.description;
                        }

                        string subcategorycodevalue, subcategorycodedesc;

                        if (categorycode == null)
                        {
                            subcategorycodevalue = "";
                            subcategorycodedesc = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            subcategorycodevalue = subcategorycode.LookupValue.ToString();
                            subcategorycodedesc = subcategorydesc.description;
                        }

                        string brandcodecodevalue, brandcodecodedesc;

                        if (brandcode == null)
                        {
                            brandcodecodevalue = "";
                            brandcodecodedesc = "";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            brandcodecodevalue = brandcode.LookupValue.ToString();
                            brandcodecodedesc = brandcode.description;
                        }

                        retList.Add(new TradeItemsExport()
                        {
                            ItemCode = item.ItemCode,
                            BarCode = item.BarCode,
                            Description = item.Description,
                            SupplierCode = item.SupplierCode,
                            SupplierStockCode = item.SupplierStockCode,
                            Product_Group_Code = "",
                            Product_Group_Desc = "",
                            SportCode = SportCodeValue,
                            SportDesc = SportDescValue,
                            GenderCode = GenderCodeValue,
                            GenderDesc = GenderCodeDesc,
                            ColourCode = ColourCodeValue,
                            ColourDesc = ColourCodeDesc,
                            SizeCode = SizeCodeValue,
                            SizeDesc = SizeCodeDesc,
                            CategoryCode = CategoryCodeValue,
                            CategoryDesc = CategoryCodeDesc,
                            subcategorycode = subcategorycodevalue,
                            subcategorydesc = subcategorycodedesc,
                            BrandsCode = brandcodecodevalue,
                            BrandsDesc = brandcodecodedesc,
                            Vat = item.Vat,
                            GrossWeight = item.Weight,
                            CommodityCode = item.CommodityCode,
                            price_exVAT = item.price_exVAT,
                            price_incVAT = item.price_incVAT,
                            currentprice_exVAT = item.currentprice_exVAT,
                            currentprice_incVAT = item.currentprice_incVAT,
                            creation_date = item.creation_date,
                            Inactive_date = item.Inactive_date,
                            status = 1
                        });

                        Console.Write(String.Format("Exporting stock item {0} with a current record of {1} of {2} \n", item.ItemCode.ToString(), count.ToString(), tradeItem.Count.ToString()));
                        EFStockItemExported _newStockitemImported = new EFStockItemExported();

                        _newStockitemImported.StockItemID = item.ItemCode;
                        _newStockitemImported.IsProcessed = true;
                        _newStockitemImported.DateImported = DateTime.Now;

                        db.EFStockItemExporteds.Add(_newStockitemImported);
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(string.Format("Stock Items to Process  [{0}] check the  table and remove entry if wish to re process.", 0));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return retList;
}
```

My problem that this takes around 30 mins to compute the results which is very slow.

This is the sql that I am doing which is a view that is the tradeitem that I am passing.

```
SELECT        
    dbo.PLSupplierAccount.SupplierAccountNumber, dbo.PLSupplierAccount.PLSupplierAccountID, dbo.PLSupplierAccount.SupplierAccountName, 
    dbo.PLSupplierAccount.SYSCurrencyID, dbo.PLSupplierAccount.MainTelephoneAreaCode, dbo.PLSupplierAccount.MainTelephoneCountryCode, 
    dbo.PLSupplierAccount.MainTelephoneSubscriberNumber, dbo.PLSupplierAccount.MainFaxCountryCode, dbo.PLSupplierAccount.MainFaxSubscriberNumber, 
    dbo.PLSupplierAccount.MainFaxAreaCode, dbo.PLSupplierContact.ContactName, dbo.PLSupplierContact.Description, dbo.PLSupplierContact.FirstName, 
    dbo.PLSupplierContact.MiddleName, dbo.PLSupplierContact.LastName, loc.AddressLine1, loc.AddressLine2, loc.AddressLine3, loc.AddressLine4, loc.PostCode, 
    loc.City, loc.County, 
    CAST(CASE WHEN loc.Country = 'Ireland' THEN 'IRL' 
              WHEN loc.Country = 'Great Britain' 
              THEN 'GBR' 
              ELSE 'ERR' 
         END AS nvarchar(3)) AS Country, 
    dbo.SYSCurrency.SYSCurrencyISOCodeID, dbo.SYSCurrency.SYSExchangeRateTypeID, dbo.SYSCurrency.Name AS CurrencyDescription, 
    dbo.SYSCurrency.Symbol AS CurrencySymbol
FROM
    dbo.PLSupplierAccount 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.PLSupplierContact ON dbo.PLSupplierAccount.PLSupplierAccountID = dbo.PLSupplierContact.PLSupplierAccountID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.PLSupplierLocation AS loc ON dbo.PLSupplierAccount.PLSupplierAccountID = loc.PLSupplierAccountID 
                                  AND dbo.PLSupplierContact.PLSupplierLocationID = loc.PLSupplierLocationID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.SYSCurrency ON dbo.PLSupplierAccount.SYSCurrencyID = dbo.SYSCurrency.SYSCurrencyID
```

My quesiton is how would I change the above to include a sub query that would do the same as this function is doing above.

The query for the codes look up which is again another view is below.

```
SELECT        
    dbo.StockItem.ItemID, dbo.StockItem.Code, dbo.StockItem.Name, dbo.StockItemSearchCatVal.SearchValueID, dbo.SearchValue.Name AS Expr1, 
    dbo.SearchCategory.Name AS Expr2
FROM
    dbo.SearchCategory 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.SearchValue ON dbo.SearchCategory.SearchCategoryID = dbo.SearchValue.SearchCategoryID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.StockItemSearchCatVal ON dbo.SearchCategory.SearchCategoryID = dbo.StockItemSearchCatVal.SearchCategoryID 
                              AND dbo.SearchValue.SearchValueID = dbo.StockItemSearchCatVal.SearchValueID 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.StockItem ON dbo.StockItemSearchCatVal.ItemID = dbo.StockItem.ItemID
```

I just feel I would get more benefit changing this into a subquery so that I am just returning the results to .net  I am using the filehelpers library to output the results set of MapTradeItems to csv so obv more things I can do the better on the server.

Obv I would need some kind of temporary table to loop through the results but how quick would that be in sql server compared to a .net for each loop.

This is the poco class which I have to reproduce to csv.

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
public class TradeItemsExport
{
    [FieldOrder(1)]
    public string ItemCode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(2)]
    public string BarCode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(3)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(4)]
    public string SupplierCode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(5)]
    public string SupplierStockCode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(6)]
    public string Product_Group_Code { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(7)]
    public string Product_Group_Desc { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(8)]
    public string SportCode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(9)]
    public string SportDesc { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(10)]
    public string GenderCode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(11)]
    public string GenderDesc { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(12)]

    public string ColourCode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(13)]
    public string ColourDesc { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(14)]
    public string SizeCode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(15)]
    public string SizeDesc { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(16)]
    public string CategoryCode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(17)]
    public string CategoryDesc { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(18)]
    public string subcategorycode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(19)]
    public string subcategorydesc { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(20)]
    public string BrandsCode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(21)]
    public string BrandsDesc { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(22)]

    public Nullable<short> Vat { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(23)]
    public decimal GrossWeight { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(24)]
    public string CommodityCode { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(25)]
    public decimal price_exVAT { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(26)]
    public Nullable<decimal> price_incVAT { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(27)]
    public Nullable<decimal> currentprice_exVAT { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(28)]
    public Nullable<decimal> currentprice_incVAT { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(29)]
    public System.DateTime creation_date { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(30)]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Inactive_date { get; set; }
    [FieldOrder(31)]
    public int status { get; set; }
   }
```

Comment: There is a lot here to get your head around. If you could simplify the problem down a bit then you may get more responses.

Comment: @mjwills i understand that but at times when I have simplied it and not given more code examples people complain so no pleasing everyone ;-)

Comment: @mjwills its bsically the bottom two quires i need to turn into  a sp that produces the poco class structure  so that i can just call the sp to produce the csv

Comment: Just turning a properly parametrized T-SQL query into a stored procedure isn't going to give you any performance benefits .....

Comment: You're using Entity Framework.   How big is 'tradeItem'?  How long does your DbContext take to load?  Try to find the bottleneck by running a query execution plan in SSMS and going from there.  EF is notorious for extremely expensive joins and lots of unknown overhead, hurting performance if you aren't careful.

Comment: Hi @cloudstrifebro there is about 38 thousand items which I did explain in my orignal query , there it takes 30 mins  thats why was wanting to change this to a stored proc but was wanting some guidance

Comment: If you used the query execution plan you can identify which parts of your queries are the most expensive and add indices as necessary to speed up the performance of your query.